# how exactly does rails callbacks work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm curious how exactly those callbacks work. If i initialize an object, and then use method `save` to throw it into my database, will `before_create` callback work?
Similar thing with `before_save`. is it called literally only before function `save` is being used, or will it be triggered also in case of using `create` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before_save` will be triggered before you save a record. It doesn't matter whether you're creating or updating a record, your callback will be triggered. So, yes, it will also be triggered when you use the `create` method.

`before_create` is only triggered before creating a record, not before updating a record.

There is also `before_update`, which is only triggered before updating, but not before creating.

This doesn't depend on which method you use, it depends on whether the record was persisted before or not. In other words, it depends on whether you're updating or creating a record.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html this url will help you find right answer for you. On this url you can also find the sequence for call back. Hope it helps you.